# Side menu and changing view controllers by button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a problem with side menu. I didn't want to use any frameworks and try to do something by my self, by the way i use this tutorial as the guide [sliding out navigation panel](https://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path). In tutorial displays how to build side menu which consist of table view and cells but i what to use a button instead cells. And here is my question: side menu works well its sliding and goes back everything correct, but i don't know how can I make navigation. I create a range of buttons add it in one IBAction an separate event by tag. And i have a range of view controllers which i want to replace when button pressed for this I create common viewController named "**currenViewController**" and  in  **viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _currentViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    _currentViewController = _messagesViewController;
    NSLog(@"TOP log %@", _currentViewController);
    currentXibName = @"MessagesViewController";

    [self setupView];
}
```

"TOP LOG" said that currentViewController is null but when i run app i see my messageViewController and everything ok. And here is my setupView method

```
- (void)setupView {
    self.currentViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:currentXibName bundle:nil];
    self.currentViewController.view.tag = CENTER_TAG;
    _currentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(70, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.headerView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.currentViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:_currentViewController];
    [_currentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self setupGestures];

}
```

But when i try to change my view controller by button click nothing happens.

```
-(IBAction)menuButtonClickSelector:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.tag == 101) {
        NSLog(@"homepressed");
        _currentViewController = _homeViewController;
        currentXibName = @"HomeViewController";
        [self changeViewController:_currentViewController xibName:currentXibName];
    } else if (sender.tag == 102) {
        NSLog(@"messagepra");
        _currentViewController = _messagesViewController;
        currentXibName = @"MessagesViewController";
        [self changeViewController:_currentViewController xibName:currentXibName];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not found tag");
    } 
}
```

and here is my changeViewController method

```
-(void)changeViewController:(UIViewController *)vc xibName:(NSString *)xibName {
    vc = _currentViewController;
    xibName = currentXibName;
    vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"view controller now %@  xib name now %@", vc, xibName);
}
```

Probably i should said that my ViewControllers xib consist of views which i add from different xib such as header and background.
I will be grateful for any help!!!